# federated google sign in issue (aws amplify and react native)

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I setup google auth with react native and aws amplify cognito. On first signIn i get this message

Sign in failure ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value '{xxx.amazonaws.com/xxx}' at 'logins' failed to satisfy constraint: Map value must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 50000, Member must have length greater than or equal to 1]

On second signIn(press button) it sign in well.

Why don't work first sign in and why get this message?

Comment: Please share your configuration and code you already have related to your problem. Otherwise chances are no one will give you any answers.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Amplify will open the Cognito Hosted UI in Safari/Chrome, but you can override that behavior by providing a custom URL opener.

To solve the issue to convert the given URL into the required form using InAppBrowser as suggested in this [ISSUE](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5228) by Ashish-Nanda comment.

```
Amplify.configure({
    ...config, oauth: {
        ...config.oauth,
        urlOpener: async function urlOpener(url, redirectUrl) {
            await InAppBrowser.isAvailable();
            const { type, url: newUrl } = await InAppBrowser.openAuth(url, redirectUrl, {
                showTitle: false,
                enableUrlBarHiding: true,
                enableDefaultShare: false,
                ephemeralWebSession: false,
            });

            // split according to ur received newURL
            const splitUrl = `myapp://?${newUrl.split("#_=_")[0].split("?")[1] || ''}`;
            if (type === 'success') {
                Linking.openURL(splitUrl);
            }
        }

    }
})
```